Lerna - publish packages a fresh to new registry
I have to migrate a monorepo from one gitlab to another.
This monorepo uses lerna to publish packages.
Is there a way to (re) publish packages a fresh on a new gitlab's package registry as per versions in the packages/* ?
my current command looks like
"lerna:publish": "lerna publish --conventional-commits --changelog-preset conventionalcommits --create-release gitlab --yes"

package.json looks like this
  "name": "root",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "api/foo-bar",
... Truncated ...
]}

